# Can I use a Java Stream Collector to implement this behavior

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a small method containing the following code:

```
final int year = getYear();
final Carrier carrier = getCarrier();
final CarrierMetrics metrics = new CarrierMetrics(carrier);
repository.getFlightStream(year)
          .filter(flight -> flight.getCarrier().equals(carrier))
          .forEach(flight -> {
             metrics.addFlight(flight);
             printf("%,10d\t%,10d\t%,10d\t%,10d\r",
                    metrics.getTotalFlights(), 
                    metrics.getTotalCancelled(), 
                    metrics.getTotalDiverted(), 
                    metrics.getAirports().size()
             );
          });
```

Hopefully it's obvious that what I am doing is accumulating metrics while processing each Flight in the stream. The code does work but I'm wondering if there is a better (more functional) way to implement this behavior, possibly using a Collector. Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks,

-Tony

Comment: Use `Collector.of` to define a custom collector.

Comment: Your peek().allMatch() is quite a convoluted way of doing a forEach().

Comment: Yes, that's the job for a Collector. But you can also use this collect() method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

Comment: Agree with the comment about using forEach instead of peek. Code updated accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the printing in the `forEach` is important,
then your current solution is good as it is.
`forEach` is designed for side effects,
and you have two side effects: adding metrics to `CarrierMetrics` instance *and* printing.

If the printing in the `forEach` is only for debugging,
and not intended in your final solution,
then a more functional implementation would be to collect results directly into a `CarrierMetrics` instance,
instead of initializing an instance first and manually adding with `forEach`.
You can use the overload of [`collect(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) that takes 3 arguments:

- A `Supplier<CarrierMetrics>` to create an initial `CarrierMetrics` instance, which will be used as an *accumulator*
- A `BiConsumer<CarrierMetrics, Flight>` that pass a `Flight` instance to the *accumulator*

  - The type `Flight` is just a guess based on the code you shared. It's the type of the stream (and so the type of the parameter of `CarrierMetrics.addFlight` method)
- A `BiConsumer<CarrierMetrics, CarrierMetrics>` that combines multiple accumulators in case of a parallel stream

Like this:

```
final int year = getYear();
final CarrierMetrics metrics = repository.getFlightStream(year)
      .filter(flight -> flight.getCarrier().equals(carrier))
      .collect(CarrierMetrics::new, CarrierMetrics::addFlight, (a1, a2) -> {});
```

The third argument, the combiner, is a dummy,
you will need to fix that.
Its implementation should combine the two `CarrierMetrics` parameters into the first one.
(I cannot give a concrete example, because you haven't shared enough details about `CarrierMetrics` to be able to see how to do.
But to give *some* example, in case of a `List` accumulators,
the implementation could be `(a1, a2) -> a1.addAll(a2)`.)

(Lastly, this example assumes that `CarrierMetrics` has a parameterless constructor, for the `CarrierMetrics::new` reference to work.
If there is no such constructor, you can use an appropriate lambda expression, such as `() -> new CarrierMetrics(...)`.)

Comment: You know the combiner isn't optional for sequential steams, right?

Comment: @janos This is similar to what I was planning to do except that in my case the constructor to CarrierMetrics requires a single parameter. Thanks for the tip about using a lambda expression here.

Comment: @TonyPiazza I addressed in an update, see the last paragraph

Comment: @shmosel why do you think it's not optional? AFAIK, the stream would be allowed to use it even for sequential streams, but in practice, AFAIK, it doesn't, and I don't see why it would. I'd still implement it just for correctness, and in case this code becomes parallel or is copied and pasted for another usecase.

Comment: @JBNizet It's not optional unless it's documented to be optional. Just because it works doesn't make it correct.

Comment: @shmosel you're probably right. I updated that part accordingly

Comment: OK, that's what I thought.

Comment: @JBNizet the `combiner` is indeed called *at the moment* only for parallel streams; but there is no specification saying that it will not be used in *any* other stream operations: being parallel or sequential.

Comment: @janos btw since `a1` and `a2` would be `CarrierFlight`s actually, your combiner is not hard to implement: `(a1, a2) -> {a1.getFlights().addAll(a2.getFlights());return a1;}`

Answer (score 0):

If `CarrierMetrics` exposing a `addAll(List<Flight> flights)` method you can do the following:

```
List<Flight> flights = repository.getFlightStream(year)
                    .filter(flight -> flight.getCarrier().equals(carrier))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
metrics.addAll(flights);
```

Comment: This particular method is printing the metrics as they are updated so waiting until they are all accumulated doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @TonyPiazza You mean that you actually want to print every evolution of the metrics while collecting? That wasn't just for debugging? Why do that?

Comment: I thought exactly like @JBNizet

Comment: @Gal that said, collecting all flight to a list in memory is wasteful, needs two passes, and doesn't allow parallelizing the metrics computation. A collector is a much better solution. Even the original solution of the OP is a better solution.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, the goal was to display the metrics as they are being collected. It's not the typical use but an important one. It would be similar to having a live dashboard that is updated as each Flight is emitted by the Stream. Hope that helps.

Comment: What kind of source for the stream are you using that is so slow that you have the time to even see intermediate results?